# mysql query to update field only if other field exist?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with these fields:

**post_id**

**meta_key**

**meta_value**

The query should clear (empty)the value of "name_value" where "meta_key" = "_sku" only if the row "meta_key" with a value "_variation_description" exist. And both have the same value in post_id a given text and remove it from the value of "meta_value" where "meta_key" is "sku".

I upload a capture to help to understand what I need.

**Let say I have these rows:**

*id_post -- meta_key -- meta_value*

63387 -- _sku -- 23454355

63387 -- _variation_description -- xxxx

63387 -- _sku -- 99978777

**Then after the query is run the results should be:**

*id_post -- meta_key -- meta_value*

63387 -- _sku --

63387 -- _variation_description -- xxxx

17633 -- _sku -- 99978777

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a update with self join

```
  update my_table m1
  inner join my_table m2 on m1.id_post = m2.id_post  
        and m2.meta_key = '_variation_description'
        and m1.meta_key = 'sku'

  set m1-meta_value =''
```

Comment: I get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where m1.meta_key = '_sku'
  set m1-meta_value =''' at line 4

Comment: I also tried with:  update wp_postmeta m1
  inner join wp_postmeta m2 on m1.post_id = m2.post_id  
        and m2.meta_key = '_variation_description'
  where m1.meta_key = '_sku'
  set m1.meta_value ='';

Comment: I made sure there is not rare characters in the code.

Comment: answer  updated .. whitout where (added  in On clause)